# Chi-squared Significance, P-values and Degrees of freedom correct use

Tags: hypothesis-testing, degrees-of-freedom

I'm in a dilemma about correct use of degrees of freedom (df) for contingency table

For example:

Set alpha <=0.05

**PREDICTOR** = ***colours***: red, green, blue

**TARGET** = ***binary***: yes, no

df formula is (r-1)(c-1).

Therefore: df = (3-1)(2-1) = 2*1 = 2

Chi-squared table = **5.991** to reach alpha <=0.05

However let's say we change the hypothesis, we want to know if colours were red or not red. i.e.

**PREDICTOR** = ***colours***: red, not_red

**TARGET** = ***binary***: yes, no

Therefore:
df = (2-1)(2-1) = 1

Chi-squared table = **3.841** to reach alpha <=0.05

The two examples are seemingly the same question, but the second example requires a much smaller chi-squared score. Is the methodology used in the second example wrong?

Comment: How is a chi-squared test applicable to prediction?  Apart from prediction, how does your question differ from asking for the DF in *any* $2\times 2$ contingency table?

Comment: Thanks, have updated the question. My issue is the discrepancy between the degrees of freedom for the two examples which would in theory have the same prediction for "red" 5.991 and 3.841. its much easier to get a significant score in the second example. Is the second example wrong methodology?

Comment: No, it's not wrong--the two procedures are testing different hypotheses.

Comment: Ok thanks i see what you mean